# How to print the selected value using checkbox and print them without getting undefined value?

Tags: javascript, html, checkbox

I have these codes here for html and javascript. I'm trying to get this result using javascript. For example, `Extras: Candy, Ice Cream`, or `Extras: Candy, Chocolate` and without getting undefined value somewhere in between or somewhere. I've tried with multiple var, but I'm getting undefined value. If I only have one selected, it only prints one and never prints the rest.

```
getCheckboxvalue() {
    var msg2 = "";

if (extras[0].checked) {
msg2 = (msg2 + "Candy");
} else if (extras[1].checked) {
msg2 = (msg2 + "Chocolate");
} else if (extras[2].checked) {
msg2 = (msg2 + "Ice Cream");
}
var message = "Extras: " + msg2;
document.getElementsByClassName("gettext")[0].innerHTML = message;
}
```

```html
<form name="elem" autocomplete="on">
  <input type="checkbox" name="extras">Candy
  <br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="extras">Chocolate
  <br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="extras">Ice Cream
  <input type="button" onClick="getCheckboxvalue()" value="Get Order!">
  <br>
  <br><span class="gettext"></span>
</form>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
function getCheckboxvalue() {
    var msg2=[];
for (var i=0;i< document.getElementsByName("extras").length;i++){
   if ( document.getElementsByName("extras")[i].checked) {
    msg2.push(document.getElementsByName("extras")[i].value);
    }
}
  
  document.getElementsByClassName("gettext")[0].innerHTML ="Extras :"+ msg2.toString();
}
```

```html
<form name="elem" autocomplete="on">
  <input type="checkbox" name="extras" value="Candy">Candy
  <br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="extras" value="Chocolate">Chocolate
  <br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="extras" value="Ice Cream">Ice Cream
  <input type="button" onClick="getCheckboxvalue();" value="Get Order!">
  <br>
  <br><span class="gettext"></span>
</form>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Tho I haven't learned arrays yet and this will be a good reference in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Set your string value of msg2 like this:

```
var msg2 = "";
```

then in your if statement make it `+=` instead of `=` .

Comment: It only prints the first selected checkbox and the other two options are getting printed.

Comment: Thats because of the fact that your are using if else statements. 
Try to make only if statements. Or make a loop that checks each checkbox if its checked

Comment: I've got it and thanks for the suggestion! Although someone beat me on getting the answer first.

Answer (score 0):

First, yeah you should set your msg2 var, like rick said.
Then, you are using **else if** conditions,if your code goes inside the first **if**, it will exit the loop and not go inside the other **else if**'s, this is why you can only put one of the values in your variable
. 
Something like this sohuld work

```
if (extras[0].checked) {
    msg2 = (msg2 + "Candy");
}
if (extras[1].checked) {
    msg2 = (msg2 + "Chocolate");
}
```

etc